# JSON Exception sending data

Tags: android, json, apache

**Error:**

```
Value <html><head><title>Apache of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject 
org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Apache of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObjectat org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
at com.avilyne.android.MainActivity.handleResponse(MainActivity.java:107)
at com.avilyne.android.MainActivity$WebServiceTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:216)
at com.avilyne.android.MainActivity$WebServiceTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code:**

```
public void handleResponse(String response) 
{     
    EditText edFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    EditText edLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
    EditText edEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    String firstName=edFirstName.getText().toString();
    String lastName=edLastName.getText().toString();
    String email=edEmail.getText().toString();

    edFirstName.setText("");
    edLastName.setText("");
    edEmail.setText("");

    try 
    {

        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response.toString());

        String jfirstName = jso.getString(firstName);
        String jlastName = jso.getString(lastName);
        String jemail = jso.getString(email);

        edFirstName.setText(jfirstName);
        edLastName.setText(jlastName);
        edEmail.setText(jemail);                      
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }    
}
```

Comment: `JSONException: Value <html><head><title>` You are not getting the JSON for some reason, you are reaching an HTML page

Comment: So how do I solve the problem

Comment: Well At least you should find a way to log the response before attempting to parse it

Comment: I tried that and the response that is going is printed as org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@414dd928

Comment: thats not it, you need to see if you app can even reach the url, This could be a 404 not found page because your response contains html. You should run the script in your browser or something to make sure it is correct

Comment: I checked the url in the browser the url is reachable and working . It is the problem with the response string

Comment: what is the server side language, share that script

Comment: http://avilyne.com/?p=105 

PersonResource.java &Person.java are the server side classes

Comment: Have you tested creating a request outside the application using something like Postman? http://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: I had solved the error their was the error with the url i was using

Answer (score 0):

The logs tell you the reason:

```
Value <html><head><title>Apache of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Strip the html tags to get the **raw Json string**, and pass it to JSONObject constructor.

Raw Json string looks like this:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How excatly do I do that

Comment: Yeas I tried to check the string which is passed using Log.d(); it has printed the html tags ... how to convert that to JSON string

Comment: Do you have that full string which is returned?